# Updating ALOM firmware Sun Fire v440

Tags: sun, bios, firmware

I have Sun Fire v440 server with old bios (or ALOM?) release. So the fans installed in the server make a lot of noise, even if processors aren't heated.

I have some image files to update bios (alombootfw (boot image file) and alommainfw (main image file)), but i found only one manual to update ALOM firmware from Solaris OS (now debian squeeze istalled).

There is *flashupdate [-s IPaddr -f pathname]* command at SC> console, but i don't know where images should be allocated that i could launch command.

How to update ALOM firmware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"flashupdate" uses FTP. 
If I remember correctly, on v440 it looks similar to this http://www.mernin.com/blog/2007/05/upgrading-the-firmware-on-a-sunfire-t2000/

Comment: ok, that works. it really ftp, not tftp