# Updating OpenBoot PROM on Sun Fire v440

Tags: ext3, sun, bios, firmware, ufs

After i have updated [ALOM firmware on Sun Fire v440,](https://serverfault.com/questions/333553/updating-alom-firmware-sun-fire-v440) i decided to update OpenBoot PROM, but when i try to load the patch using

```
boot disk /flash-update-SunFire440
```

i get:

```
SILO

Fatal Error: Multiple loadable segments in your ELF image
Program terminated
```

I found that possibly problem is in [file system of root partition](http://www.sunhelp.org/pipermail/rescue/2000-June/009714.html). (I have *ext3* with *debian squeeze* installed on it). Should i only have *UFS* file system on root partition, or *Solaris OS* installed to update OBP?

Reason we are doing this is fan noise which drives us crazy. Any other way to take fan noise under control besides upgrading is appreciated.