# Lowering fans noise level on Sun Fire v440

Tags: sun, sparc, fan

Sun Fire v440 has been placed in the same room, where i'm working. It seems that it makes much more noise, than reactive plane does.

I've already updated [ALOM Firmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/333553/updating-alom-firmware-sun-fire-v440) and even [OpenBoot PROM](https://serverfault.com/questions/334695/updating-openboot-prom-on-sun-fire-v440), expecting that there were some new features in these updates. But I haven't found anything interesting…

Is there some other way to reduce the noise level except power off server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servers are noisy, that's what they do.

You have three options;

1. use hacks/updates to disable or reduce the fan speed forcefully
2. replace the internal moving (noisy) components with quieter ones
3. [Buy a noise reduction cabinet](http://www.acoustiproducts.com/en/acoustirack_active.asp)
4. Move the server into a proper server room

1 is stupid, reducing the fan speed is **NEVER** a suitable option, 2, 3 and 4 will cost. Up to you, there is no magical software fix that will make servers quieter.